# Phone and tablet resolutions are too high for media queries

Tags: css

I might be completely off the mark, but here goes:

I tried testing my website with various modern phones and tablets... and the result is that my media queries never come into effect because these phone/tablet resolutions are too high.

Things like `@media (max-width: 767px) { }`, which I want to display for phones, never come into effect because of this resolution problem. Any ideas on how to solve this? This can't be an uncommon problem so I feel like I'm overlooking something.

Comment: Is [`<meta name="viewport" width="device-width">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Configured correctly, "retina" screens take the increased resolution into account when rendering web pages. I'd take a look at [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template), purely as an example of how to setup your page to be fully responsive.

You'll find once you have this setup, it will work regardless of the actual physical resolution of the device. For example, the first iPhone to have a retina screen (iPhone 4, perhaps?) had a "width" of 320px, regardless of the fact that it's resolution was far higher than that.